# IIS 7 issue - HTTP Error 403.4 - Forbidden

Tags: iis-7.5, https

We have a site set up under IIS7 that requires SSL.

If the user accesses it by typing in https://www.site.com it comes up but if they type any of the following in the address bar...:

http://site.com
http://www.site.com
site.com
www.site.com

...IIS returns the following error page:

```
HTTP Error 403.4 - Forbidden
The page you are trying to access is secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).
```

How do I tweak the settings so that if a user navigates to any of the above that IIS will automatically take them to https://www.site.com ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways:

The easiest is simply to create a web site bound on port 80 containing only a default page with a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://www.site.com/">
```

A little more complex: install [URL rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) for IIS and configure it to forward all HTTP request to the equvalent HTTPS request. Watch it because you might need to rewrite the host name as well (see [this](http://forums.iis.net/t/1153050.aspx) for a simple exemple)

Comment: The IIS redirect module will work just fine, too.